# Cannot connect with a Google Service Account via php and google apiclient alpha 2.0.0

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client, service-accounts

I'm having a problem connecting through the google apiclient 2.0.0 as installed via composer.

Here's what I've done so far:

I installed apiclient via composer.

I went to https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?my-project and navigated to the API manager > Credentials page.

I created credentials for a Service Account and downloaded the json. I then uploaded the json to my server.

I enabled Domain Wide Delegation for the account by managing my service accounts.

I verified my domain name under the 'Domain Verification' tab.

Next I navigated to my calendar and shared the calendar with the email address associated with my service account, granting manage access.

Then I shared my calendar with the email address of the service account.

Now I'm trying to use the api to connect and running into authorization problems.

```
$json_file = '/path/to/service-account-credentials.json';
$scopes = [ 
    Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR,
    Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY
];

// create a new client and authorize
$client = new Google_Client();

// set the basic information of the client
$client->setApplicationName("Apointments");
$client->setSubject( email-address-to-masquerade-as@mycompany.com );
$client->setAccessType('offline');

// load the json credential file
$client->setAuthConfig( $json_file );
$client->setScopes( $scopes );

// check to see if the token is stored in the session
if( isset( $_SESSION['service_token'] ) ) 
{
    // token was stored, use it with the cilent
    $client->setAccessToken( $_SESSION['service_token'] );
}

// test the authorization to see if it is expired
if( $client->isAccessTokenExpired() ) 
{
    // Failed authorization, get a new token
    $client->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
}
// store the token in the session
$_SESSION['service_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
```

From a stacktrace, I've identified the offending line of code to be:

```
    $client->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
```

Which yields an error message:

> Client error response [url] https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token [status code] 401 [reason phrase] Unauthorized

Any thoughts as to where I've gone awry?

Thanks in advance,
Adam

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using Service account is only valid to access data related to your application or to your service account itself. Since you wish to access [`Google Calendar`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/) data, you must be a Google Apps domain administrator with privileges to access any of your domain user's data. Google Calendar data belong to users so you need to specify which user you are trying to access.

You need to [`authenticate`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) the user, need to get an access token and pass that. If you are getting an access token, you can call token info passing access token to get more information about who the user is associated with it.

Here's a Quick start demo app, use this as your reference: https://developers.google.com/+/web/samples/php

Comment: Correct, I only want to access my own account's data. I do not want to access another user's data. I have an admin account that has a calendar. I want to access my admin account's calendar and manipulate the data.